# SVG in D3--scaling across browsers

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

Instead of generic SVG shapes, I want to bind external SVG icons to my data with D3. I can do that like this

```
group = svg.selectAll("g")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("g");
group.append("svg:image")
     .attr("xlink:href",path)
     .attr(...)
```

etc but I run into several scaling issues. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkpxc0ch/10/) embeds an exemplary icon. Running it in three different browsers, I get three different renderings. Chrome does it best:

[image: Chrome]

Edge:

[image: Edge]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

I've added a `viewPort` attribute, which appears in various guides on how to scale SVGs, but it doesn't seem to do anything no matter the coordinates I set it to. How can I make the scaling behave like in Chrome in all browsers?

Comment: I believe that is at least a known issue in Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804950/include-one-svg-inside-another

Comment: Well that's bad news! I hoped SVG would improve my visualizations :( However in my case there's no rasterization so there must have been some improvement in the engines at least..