# <image> causes pixelated image

Tags: svg

I want to create a SVG with repeated elements. Therefore, I created a SVG of the image that I want to use multiple times and I include it by using the `<image>` tag ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg)). Let us call this multiple-use-image "M" and let us call the SVG file with the `<image>` tag "S".

The Problem: 
No SVG Viewer antialiases image M.

For example, if I use ImageMagick to convert the final SVG to a PNG I use

```
convert -antialias -density 2000 file.svg -quality 100 file.png
```

Yet, image M is not rendered with 2000 DPI and completely pixelated whereas the shapes directly created in S look perfect.

For example in S.svg:

```
<image xlink:href="M.svg" /> <!-- This looks pixelated -->
<path d="M 0 0 50 50" stroke="black" /> <!-- This looks crisp -->
```

How can I make programs, any program, render image M at higher DPI?

Comment: Does `M.svg` contain a bitmap image? It is possible to include a `.png` inside of an svg image, but that won't magically convert it to a vector representation.

Comment: @DanRoss: `M.svg` does not contain bitmap images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the included image (is it used somewhere else?), you could include it in your main SVG as well using [`<defs>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/defs) and [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/use).

This lets you define groups within an SVG, that are used multiple times throughout the SVG. Seems like a perfect fit here.

An example would be something like this:

```svg
<svg viewBox = "0 0 1000 1000" version = "1.1">
    <defs>
      <g id="myGroup">
        <circle cx = "200" cy = "200" r = "200" fill = "yellow" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3"/>
        <!-- your included image's content basically in here -->
      </g>
    </defs>

    <use x = "100" y = "100" xlink:href = "#myGroup"/>
    <use x = "100" y = "650" xlink:href = "#myGroup"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works for me but Firefox seems to ignore `width` and `height` properties of `use` although they are explicitly listed at the website you linked.

Comment: @Throwaway647172 Maybe create a fiddle and ask a new question for that :-)

Comment: width and height properties of use are treated as additional transforms to whatever width and height are specified in the defs. Firefox tends to be a stickler for making you specify things you're supposed to specify: it doesn't fill in missing values with plausible defaults.