# How many levels of recursion does SVG support?

Tags: svg

I cannot get past 2 levels.  (Tried on Iceweasel and Chromium.)

As a test, I tried a variant of the code presented in [this earlier reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451238).  This one consists of 3 separate files, where `a.svg` includes `b.svg`, and `b.svg` includes `c.svg`.  (**NB:** *This is not a cycle.*)

```
<!-- a.svg -->
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="30" style="fill:#b58900" />
  <image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="b.svg" />
</svg>
```

```
<!-- b.svg -->
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="30" style="fill:#cb4b16" />
  <image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="c.svg" />
</svg>
```

```
<!-- c.svg -->
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="30" style="fill:#dc322f" />
</svg>
```

I expected to see a large dark yellow dot, a medium-sized orange dot, and a small red dot, but I see only the first two.  In fact, what I see is exactly the same as what I would see if `b.svg` did not include `c.svg`.

Why is `c.svg` not being included?

Is there a way to get SVG recursion to work for more than 2 levels?

Comment: I've uploaded the test files above to [a.svg](http://phrogz.net/tmp/a.svg), [b.svg](http://phrogz.net/tmp/b.svg), [c.svg](http://phrogz.net/tmp/c.svg), with the addition of colored rectangles behind each image (to show where they should be). You can use the Developer Tools of Chrome to show that `c.svg` never attempts to load.

Comment: If you post your use case you may get some very good recommendations on how to achieve what you're looking for. For example, you can have `<svg>`s inside other `<svg>`s and can manipulate this DOM with Javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SVG when used as an image must be complete in a single file.

- a.svg is not an image
- b.svg is included as an image by a.svg and is therefore subject to the complete in a single file image rule so any images it contains must be included as [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
- c.svg is ignored as b.svg cannot refer to external files.

Convert c.svg to a data URI and include it inline in b.svg to get round this.

Comment: This is very good to know. Your profile leads me to think you may know a thing or two about this :)