# Custom SVG is not loading in my image tag

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

Currently I'm trying to load in my custom svg component inside an image tag. But for some reason I am unable to see the svg image which is inside a map component. My custom SVG file is like so where I am loading another image inside the SVG:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="85.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 850 1090" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path id="path" transform="translate(0,1090) scale(1,-1)" d="M406 1035 c-32 -49 -201 -104 -323 -105 l-43 0 0 -282 c0 -277 1
    -284 24 -333 39 -82 146 -174 291 -250 l67 -34 61 31 c151 76 265 170 303 253
    23 49 24 57 24 330 l0 281 -103 12 c-124 13 -206 42 -252 87 l-33 34 -16 -24z" />
  </clipPath>

  <image x="-200" y="30" width="1090" height="1090" clip-path="url(#clip)" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" />

  <use xlink:href="#path" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="30" />
</svg>
```

And my image tag is like so:

```
<img src="icon.svg"/>
```

But when I go to check the network tab this is what it shows:

[image]

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-6rupe?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure if there's an issue with external/cross-domain image resources in codesandbox (could also be an issue developing locally). The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903224/how-many-levels-of-recursion-does-svg-support) Robert tagged leads me to believe the issue is with this specific SVG asset itself.

But there is still a way to render it.

Import the svg image as a `ReactComponent` and render it instead of the `img` tag.

[Source](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs)

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon} from "./icon.svg";

...

<Icon
  style={{
    width: 48,
    height: 48
  }}
  onMouseEnter={() => {
    setSelectedProperty(item);
    setIsPopupShown(true);
  }}
  onMouseOut={() => {
    setSelectedProperty(null);
    setIsPopupShown(false);
  }}
/>
```

[image]