# Why image or img no tag is working in svg?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have a svg file. The svg contains a image. But the image is not showing when I use the svg in src attribute of another image. [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903224/how-many-levels-of-recursion-does-svg-support) demonstarates that images of more than two levels do not appear. But my image is at first level (It is the only image child of main svg). I've tried both `<img>` tag and `<image>` tag; all of them works when I visit the svg url or open svg locally, but don't work when used in src attribute. I've also appiled inline width and height to image but still in vain.

I'm providing the full code of svg here:

```html
<svg width="410" height="310" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
    svg {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 21px;
    }
    
    #background {
      width: calc(100% - 10px);
      height: calc(100% - 10px);
      fill: transparent;
      stroke: rgb(225, 228, 232);
      stroke-width: 0px;
    }
    
    foreignObject {
      width: calc(100% - 10px - 32px);
      height: calc(100% - 10px - 32px);
    }
    .main {
      width: 410;
      height: 310;
      border: 1px solid #e1e4e8;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #fffefe;
      background-image: none;
    }
    .container {
      width: 310px;
      height: 210px;
      padding: 5%;
      padding-top: 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .title {
      transform: translateX(4%);
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #434d58;
    }
    img {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }
    </style>
    <g>
    <rect x="5" y="5" id="background" />
    <g>
       
    <foreignObject x="21" y="21" width="318" height="168">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
             <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" alt="avatar" />
             <!--<image href="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" />-->
      </div>
      <div class="title">KasRoudra</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </foreignObject>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KasRoudra2/files2/main/test.svg) you can see how it looks like when used in src attribute.

[Here](https://i.ibb.co/PrH50t1/Screenshot-2022-04-11-13-53-11.jpg) you can check the desired output which I get locally.

Comment: I see the image. which browser are you using?

Comment: Check your browser console: *"Refused to load the image 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."*

Comment: _"The svg contains a image."_ - well to be more precise, it contains a `foreignObject`- which then in turn contains HTML, that contains an HTML image tag. Do you actually need that foreignObject ...? If not, you should rather use [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image).

Comment: @vsync I am using brave browser. It's chrome based. What about yours?

Comment: @vsync have you tried it as the src of an img element? The svg shows when used by itself but is not showing correctly when used as a src.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Unfortunately, my browser doesn't give any error in console. It's brave. Do you know how to solve that error?

Comment: @CBroe Without the foreignObject everything becomes white blank div. I've already mentioned that I tried `image` tag but it was still the same