# SVG cuts off text on some devices

Tags: google-chrome, svg, text

My SVG file (that I've added to my html file as an `<img>`) cuts off on some web browsers and on some PCs. I've tried to run it on other devices as well but as far as I've tried, it works well on MacxChrome, MacxSafari, MacxFirefox, WindowsxChrome, but not on WindowsxEdge and other WindowsxChrome as well. It works fine on mobile so far.

[Cut text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeKth.png)

I've tried to add `overflow-x: visible` and checked to see if the svg file clips on any path but those solutions don't work.

If anyone can provide even an inkling to any insight, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 312.35 218.01">
      <defs>
        <style>
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;900');

          .cls-1 {
            letter-spacing: 0em;
          }

          .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4 {
            fill: #fff;
          }

          .cls-5 {
            fill: #fc0;
          }

          .cls-6 {
            fill: #ff2400;
          }

          .cls-7 {
            fill: #a30a24;
          }

          .cls-8 {
            letter-spacing: 0em;
          }

          .cls-9 {
            letter-spacing: -.04em;
          }

          .cls-10 {
            letter-spacing: 0em;
          }

          .cls-11 {
            letter-spacing: -.01em;
          }

          .cls-3 {
            font-family: "Lato";
            font-size: 11.99px;
            font-weight: 900;
          }

          .cls-12 {
            letter-spacing: 0em;
          }

          .cls-4 {
            font-family: "Lato";
            font-size: 11.55px;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <g>
          <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(148.63 188.07)"><tspan class="cls-11" x="0" y="0">March 25, 2024 | 9AM to 5PM</tspan></text>
          
          <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(148.86 205.52)"><tspan x="0" y="0">ES Plaza, Los Baños, Laguna</tspan></text>
          
          
          <polygon class="cls-2" points="254.79 171.66 137.96 171.66 137.96 148.36 259.28 148.36 254.79 171.66"/>
          <rect class="cls-2" y="148.36" width="116.48" height="23.3"/>
          <g>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m147.81,169.19l6.08-17.4h5.08l5.75,17.4h-4.78l-.63-1.95h-6.16l-.67,1.95h-4.69Zm6.62-6.3h3.58l-1.79-5.87-1.78,5.87Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m166.29,169.19v-17.4h4.92c2.29,0,4.04.47,5.25,1.41,1.21.94,1.81,2.3,1.81,4.09,0,1.03-.25,1.92-.74,2.68s-1.16,1.28-2.02,1.57l3.83,7.64h-4.94l-3.6-7.45v7.45h-4.5Zm4.5-9.22h.44c.81,0,1.42-.18,1.85-.55.42-.37.63-.9.63-1.61s-.2-1.26-.61-1.63c-.41-.38-.99-.56-1.75-.56h-.56v4.36Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m187.41,156.19v13h-4.53v-13h-3.53l.46-4.4h10.63l.49,4.4h-3.53Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m199.37,169.19v-17.4h9.54l.7,4.62h-5.74v1.77h3.6v4.6h-3.6v6.4h-4.5Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m208.4,169.19l6.08-17.4h5.08l5.75,17.4h-4.78l-.63-1.95h-6.16l-.67,1.95h-4.69Zm6.62-6.3h3.58l-1.79-5.87-1.78,5.87Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m231.55,169.19h-4.5v-17.4h4.5v17.4Z"/>
            <path class="cls-7" d="m234.71,169.19v-17.4h4.92c2.29,0,4.04.47,5.25,1.41,1.21.94,1.81,2.3,1.81,4.09,0,1.03-.25,1.92-.74,2.68s-1.16,1.28-2.02,1.57l3.83,7.64h-4.94l-3.6-7.45v7.45h-4.5Zm4.5-9.22h.44c.81,0,1.42-.18,1.85-.55.42-.37.63-.9.63-1.61s-.2-1.26-.61-1.63c-.41-.38-.99-.56-1.75-.56h-.56v4.36Z"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path class="cls-2" d="m284.25,29.15h8.4v17.44h16.98v8.16h-16.98v17.51h-8.4v-17.51h-16.99v-8.16h16.99v-17.44Z"/>
            <g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m99.17,85.09V3.74h21.06v28.45h17.73V3.74h21.06v81.35h-21.06v-31.62h-17.73v31.62h-21.06Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m217.2,79.42c-3.48,2.22-7.16,3.89-11.03,5-3.87,1.11-7.94,1.67-12.2,1.67-8.93,0-16.15-2.74-21.67-8.22-5.52-5.48-8.28-12.59-8.28-21.34s2.9-15.91,8.7-21.84c5.8-5.93,12.92-8.89,21.37-8.89,6.22,0,11.67,1.76,16.34,5.28,4.67,3.52,8.06,8.43,10.17,14.73l-31.28,22c1,.41,2.04.71,3.11.92,1.07.2,2.28.31,3.61.31,3.15,0,6.4-.74,9.75-2.22,3.35-1.48,6.66-3.65,9.92-6.5l1.5,19.12Zm-35.45-23.06l17.78-12.84c-.78-.78-1.67-1.34-2.67-1.69-1-.35-2.17-.53-3.5-.53-3.19,0-5.97,1.22-8.36,3.67s-3.58,5.28-3.58,8.5c0,.44.03.91.08,1.39.06.48.14.98.25,1.5Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m223.2,85.09V26.57h19.23v6.06c1.37-2.15,3.09-3.76,5.17-4.83,2.07-1.07,4.63-1.67,7.67-1.78l.06,20.17h-2.28c-3.45,0-6.08.94-7.89,2.83-1.82,1.89-2.72,4.61-2.72,8.17v27.9h-19.23Z"/>
              </g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m101.67,83.06V1.71h21.06v28.45h17.73V1.71h21.06v81.35h-21.06v-31.62h-17.73v31.62h-21.06Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m219.7,77.39c-3.48,2.22-7.16,3.89-11.03,5-3.87,1.11-7.94,1.67-12.2,1.67-8.93,0-16.15-2.74-21.67-8.22-5.52-5.48-8.28-12.59-8.28-21.34s2.9-15.91,8.7-21.84c5.8-5.93,12.92-8.89,21.37-8.89,6.22,0,11.67,1.76,16.34,5.28,4.67,3.52,8.06,8.43,10.17,14.73l-31.28,22c1,.41,2.04.71,3.11.92,1.07.2,2.28.31,3.61.31,3.15,0,6.4-.74,9.75-2.22,3.35-1.48,6.66-3.65,9.92-6.5l1.5,19.12Zm-35.45-23.06l17.78-12.84c-.78-.78-1.67-1.34-2.67-1.69-1-.35-2.17-.53-3.5-.53-3.19,0-5.97,1.22-8.36,3.67s-3.58,5.28-3.58,8.5c0,.44.03.91.08,1.39.06.48.14.98.25,1.5Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m225.7,83.06V24.55h19.23v6.06c1.37-2.15,3.09-3.76,5.17-4.83,2.07-1.07,4.63-1.67,7.67-1.78l.06,20.17h-2.28c-3.45,0-6.08.94-7.89,2.83-1.82,1.89-2.72,4.61-2.72,8.17v27.9h-19.23Z"/>
              </g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m104.61,81.35V0h21.06v28.45h17.73V0h21.06v81.35h-21.06v-31.62h-17.73v31.62h-21.06Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m222.64,75.68c-3.48,2.22-7.16,3.89-11.03,5-3.87,1.11-7.94,1.67-12.2,1.67-8.93,0-16.15-2.74-21.67-8.22-5.52-5.48-8.28-12.59-8.28-21.34s2.9-15.91,8.7-21.84c5.8-5.93,12.92-8.89,21.37-8.89,6.22,0,11.67,1.76,16.34,5.28,4.67,3.52,8.06,8.43,10.17,14.73l-31.28,22c1,.41,2.04.71,3.11.92,1.07.2,2.28.31,3.61.31,3.15,0,6.4-.74,9.75-2.22,3.35-1.48,6.66-3.65,9.92-6.5l1.5,19.12Zm-35.45-23.06l17.78-12.84c-.78-.78-1.67-1.34-2.67-1.69-1-.35-2.17-.53-3.5-.53-3.19,0-5.97,1.22-8.36,3.67s-3.58,5.28-3.58,8.5c0,.44.03.91.08,1.39.06.48.14.98.25,1.5Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m228.65,81.35V22.84h19.23v6.06c1.37-2.15,3.09-3.76,5.17-4.83,2.07-1.07,4.63-1.67,7.67-1.78l.06,20.17h-2.28c-3.45,0-6.08.94-7.89,2.83-1.82,1.89-2.72,4.61-2.72,8.17v27.9h-19.23Z"/>
              </g>
            </g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m100.5,139.43v-10.6c.66.3,1.26.52,1.78.66.52.14,1.02.21,1.49.21.86,0,1.54-.21,2.06-.63s.77-.96.77-1.62c0-.88-.93-2.17-2.8-3.89-.45-.41-.81-.74-1.09-1-1.01-.96-1.76-2.01-2.26-3.13-.5-1.12-.76-2.33-.76-3.61,0-3.19,1.15-5.69,3.45-7.5,2.3-1.81,5.5-2.71,9.59-2.71.77,0,1.58.04,2.43.13.85.09,1.75.21,2.71.39v9.96c-.64-.32-1.27-.56-1.9-.71-.62-.15-1.22-.22-1.8-.22-.84,0-1.49.18-1.98.53-.48.35-.72.83-.72,1.43,0,.39.13.79.39,1.2s.78,1.03,1.57,1.85c2.12,2.08,3.53,3.83,4.22,5.25.7,1.42,1.04,3,1.04,4.74,0,3.13-1.03,5.55-3.1,7.28-2.07,1.72-4.97,2.59-8.72,2.59-.73,0-1.55-.04-2.46-.11-.91-.08-2.22-.23-3.94-.47Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m131.41,138.18v79.83h-11.12v-112.08h10.92v3.24c1.37-1.24,2.77-2.15,4.21-2.71,1.43-.57,3.02-.85,4.75-.85,4.28,0,7.93,1.67,10.94,5.01,3.01,3.34,4.51,7.42,4.51,12.24,0,5.05-1.57,9.23-4.71,12.53-3.14,3.3-7.07,4.95-11.81,4.95-1.5,0-2.88-.18-4.14-.53-1.26-.35-2.45-.89-3.57-1.62Zm6.71-9.35c1.71,0,3.16-.58,4.35-1.75s1.78-2.58,1.78-4.22-.6-3.1-1.8-4.29c-1.2-1.19-2.65-1.78-4.34-1.78s-3.14.59-4.35,1.77c-1.21,1.18-1.82,2.61-1.82,4.3s.6,3.08,1.8,4.24c1.2,1.16,2.66,1.73,4.37,1.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m186.83,136.48c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75-3.19-3.17-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34s1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.28,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.83,2.12s-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92c0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m212.47,139.5c-1.05.26-2.09.45-3.13.58-1.04.13-2.09.19-3.16.19-4.99,0-9.04-1.64-12.16-4.92-3.12-3.28-4.67-7.56-4.67-12.85s1.64-9.12,4.92-12.26c3.28-3.14,7.55-4.71,12.82-4.71.92,0,1.83.06,2.73.19.9.13,1.79.33,2.67.61v11.05c-1.07-.28-1.98-.48-2.73-.61-.75-.13-1.41-.19-1.99-.19-2.23,0-3.96.55-5.19,1.64-1.23,1.09-1.85,2.61-1.85,4.56s.65,3.41,1.94,4.56c1.3,1.16,3.01,1.73,5.16,1.73.6,0,1.27-.04,2.01-.13.74-.09,1.62-.21,2.65-.39v10.92Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m230.56,139.76c-.84.13-1.62.22-2.36.29-.74.06-1.46.1-2.17.1-3.68,0-6.22-.77-7.6-2.3-1.38-1.53-2.07-4.73-2.07-9.59v-12.24h-2.12v-10.09h2.12v-3.6l11.12-6.46v10.05h4.21v10.09h-4.21v7.61c0,1.84.22,3.06.66,3.66.44.6,1.27.9,2.49.9.47,0,.85-.01,1.14-.03.29-.02.57-.06.85-.13l-2.06,11.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m234.32,102.97v-10.25h11.12v10.25h-11.12Zm0,36.78v-33.83h11.12v33.83h-11.12Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m254.53,139.76l-8.35-33.83h11.73l3.41,20.59,3.5-20.59h11.69l-8.29,33.83h-13.69Z"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="m306.12,136.48c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75s-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34,1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.28,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.84,2.12s-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92c0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
              </g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m101.96,138.14v-10.6c.66.3,1.26.52,1.78.66.52.14,1.02.21,1.49.21.86,0,1.54-.21,2.06-.63s.77-.96.77-1.62c0-.88-.93-2.17-2.8-3.89-.45-.41-.81-.74-1.09-1-1.01-.96-1.76-2.01-2.26-3.13-.5-1.12-.76-2.33-.76-3.61,0-3.19,1.15-5.69,3.45-7.5,2.3-1.81,5.5-2.71,9.59-2.71.77,0,1.58.04,2.43.13.85.09,1.75.21,2.71.39v9.96c-.64-.32-1.27-.56-1.9-.71-.62-.15-1.22-.22-1.8-.22-.84,0-1.49.18-1.98.53-.48.35-.72.83-.72,1.43,0,.39.13.79.39,1.2s.78,1.03,1.57,1.85c2.12,2.08,3.53,3.83,4.22,5.25.7,1.42,1.04,3,1.04,4.74,0,3.13-1.03,5.55-3.1,7.28-2.07,1.72-4.97,2.59-8.72,2.59-.73,0-1.55-.04-2.46-.11-.91-.08-2.22-.23-3.94-.47Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m132.87,136.89v81.13h-11.12v-113.38h10.92v3.24c1.37-1.24,2.77-2.15,4.21-2.71,1.43-.57,3.02-.85,4.75-.85,4.28,0,7.93,1.67,10.94,5.01,3.01,3.34,4.51,7.42,4.51,12.24,0,5.05-1.57,9.23-4.71,12.53-3.14,3.3-7.07,4.95-11.81,4.95-1.5,0-2.88-.18-4.14-.53-1.26-.35-2.45-.89-3.57-1.62Zm6.71-9.35c1.71,0,3.16-.58,4.35-1.75s1.78-2.58,1.78-4.22-.6-3.1-1.8-4.29c-1.2-1.19-2.65-1.78-4.34-1.78s-3.14.59-4.35,1.77c-1.21,1.18-1.82,2.61-1.82,4.3s.6,3.08,1.8,4.24c1.2,1.16,2.66,1.73,4.37,1.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m188.29,135.18c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75-3.19-3.17-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34s1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.28,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.83,2.12s-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92c0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m213.93,138.2c-1.05.26-2.09.45-3.13.58-1.04.13-2.09.19-3.16.19-4.99,0-9.04-1.64-12.16-4.92-3.12-3.28-4.67-7.56-4.67-12.85s1.64-9.12,4.92-12.26c3.28-3.14,7.55-4.71,12.82-4.71.92,0,1.83.06,2.73.19.9.13,1.79.33,2.67.61v11.05c-1.07-.28-1.98-.48-2.73-.61-.75-.13-1.41-.19-1.99-.19-2.23,0-3.96.55-5.19,1.64-1.23,1.09-1.85,2.61-1.85,4.56s.65,3.41,1.94,4.56c1.3,1.16,3.01,1.73,5.16,1.73.6,0,1.27-.04,2.01-.13.74-.09,1.62-.21,2.65-.39v10.92Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m232.01,138.46c-.84.13-1.62.22-2.36.29-.74.06-1.46.1-2.17.1-3.68,0-6.22-.77-7.6-2.3-1.38-1.53-2.07-4.73-2.07-9.59v-12.24h-2.12v-10.09h2.12v-3.6l11.12-6.46v10.05h4.21v10.09h-4.21v7.61c0,1.84.22,3.06.66,3.66.44.6,1.27.9,2.49.9.47,0,.85-.01,1.14-.03.29-.02.57-.06.85-.13l-2.06,11.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m235.78,101.68v-10.25h11.12v10.25h-11.12Zm0,36.78v-33.83h11.12v33.83h-11.12Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m255.99,138.46l-8.35-33.83h11.73l3.41,20.59,3.5-20.59h11.69l-8.29,33.83h-13.69Z"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="m307.58,135.18c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75s-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34,1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.28,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.84,2.12-1.38,1.41-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92,0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
              </g>
              <g>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m103.44,136.91v-10.6c.66.3,1.26.52,1.78.66.52.14,1.02.21,1.49.21.86,0,1.54-.21,2.06-.63s.77-.96.77-1.62c0-.88-.93-2.17-2.8-3.89-.45-.41-.81-.74-1.09-1-1.01-.96-1.76-2.01-2.26-3.13-.5-1.12-.76-2.33-.76-3.61,0-3.19,1.15-5.69,3.45-7.5,2.3-1.81,5.5-2.71,9.59-2.71.77,0,1.58.04,2.43.13.85.09,1.75.21,2.71.39v9.96c-.64-.32-1.27-.56-1.9-.71-.62-.15-1.22-.22-1.8-.22-.84,0-1.49.18-1.98.53-.48.35-.72.83-.72,1.43,0,.39.13.79.39,1.2s.78,1.03,1.57,1.85c2.12,2.08,3.53,3.83,4.22,5.25.7,1.42,1.04,3,1.04,4.74,0,3.13-1.03,5.55-3.1,7.28-2.07,1.72-4.97,2.59-8.72,2.59-.73,0-1.55-.04-2.46-.11-.91-.08-2.22-.23-3.94-.47Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m134.35,135.66v82.36h-11.12v-114.61h10.92v3.24c1.37-1.24,2.77-2.15,4.21-2.71,1.43-.57,3.02-.85,4.75-.85,4.28,0,7.93,1.67,10.94,5.01,3.01,3.34,4.51,7.42,4.51,12.24,0,5.05-1.57,9.23-4.71,12.53-3.14,3.3-7.07,4.95-11.81,4.95-1.5,0-2.88-.18-4.14-.53-1.26-.35-2.45-.89-3.57-1.62Zm6.71-9.35c1.71,0,3.16-.58,4.35-1.75,1.19-1.17,1.78-2.58,1.78-4.22s-.6-3.1-1.8-4.29c-1.2-1.19-2.65-1.78-4.34-1.78s-3.14.59-4.35,1.77c-1.21,1.18-1.82,2.61-1.82,4.3s.6,3.08,1.8,4.24c1.2,1.16,2.66,1.73,4.37,1.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m189.76,133.95c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75-3.19-3.17-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34s1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.29,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.83,2.12-1.38,1.41-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92,0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m215.4,136.97c-1.05.26-2.09.45-3.13.58-1.04.13-2.09.19-3.16.19-4.99,0-9.04-1.64-12.16-4.92-3.12-3.28-4.67-7.56-4.67-12.85s1.64-9.12,4.92-12.26c3.28-3.14,7.55-4.71,12.82-4.71.92,0,1.83.06,2.73.19.9.13,1.79.33,2.67.61v11.05c-1.07-.28-1.98-.48-2.73-.61-.75-.13-1.41-.19-1.99-.19-2.23,0-3.96.55-5.19,1.64-1.23,1.09-1.85,2.61-1.85,4.56s.65,3.41,1.94,4.56c1.3,1.16,3.01,1.73,5.16,1.73.6,0,1.27-.04,2.01-.13.74-.09,1.62-.21,2.65-.39v10.92Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m233.49,137.23c-.84.13-1.62.22-2.36.29-.74.06-1.46.1-2.17.1-3.68,0-6.22-.77-7.6-2.3-1.38-1.53-2.07-4.73-2.07-9.59v-12.24h-2.12v-10.09h2.12v-3.6l11.12-6.46v10.06h4.21v10.09h-4.21v7.61c0,1.84.22,3.06.66,3.66.44.6,1.27.9,2.49.9.47,0,.85-.01,1.14-.03.29-.02.57-.06.85-.13l-2.06,11.73Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m237.25,100.45v-10.25h11.12v10.25h-11.12Zm0,36.78v-33.83h11.12v33.83h-11.12Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m257.46,137.23l-8.35-33.83h11.73l3.41,20.59,3.5-20.59h11.69l-8.29,33.83h-13.69Z"/>
                <path class="cls-2" d="m309.06,133.95c-2.01,1.29-4.14,2.25-6.38,2.89-2.24.64-4.59.96-7.05.96-5.16,0-9.34-1.58-12.53-4.75-3.19-3.17-4.79-7.28-4.79-12.34s1.68-9.2,5.03-12.63c3.35-3.43,7.47-5.14,12.35-5.14,3.6,0,6.75,1.02,9.44,3.05,2.7,2.03,4.66,4.87,5.88,8.51l-18.09,12.72c.58.24,1.18.41,1.8.53.62.12,1.32.18,2.09.18,1.82,0,3.7-.43,5.64-1.29,1.94-.86,3.85-2.11,5.73-3.76l.87,11.05Zm-20.5-13.33l10.28-7.42c-.45-.45-.96-.78-1.54-.98-.58-.2-1.25-.31-2.02-.31-1.84,0-3.45.71-4.84,2.12-1.38,1.41-2.07,3.05-2.07,4.92,0,.26.02.52.05.8.03.28.08.57.14.87Z"/>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: try `overflow` instead of overflow-x

Comment: So found out that it does not just cut my text; the SVG does not read the attribute font-family even with the import link included in the <style> tag. It cuts of the text because the text is too wide and goes beyond the viewBox of the SVG. 

Resizing the viewBox doesn't look good to me so I have to really change the font-family of the text. 

The font-family included is Lato from Google fonts, but the actual font used when the text is cut off is just sans-serif.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my issue but I didn't solve the problem.

The problem was the text was too large to fit in the viewBox so I changed the font weight for the text to fit. But the problem still stands -- certain font-families don't work on certain browsers and on certain devices.

I tried to import the font, used the @font-face rule and also included a font-family attribute to the  tag. Worked on most browsers but not all.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903224/how-many-levels-of-recursion-does-svg-support/35903727#35903727

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to use [the textLength attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength). It works if the text is more or less the same.

Here are some examples:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <rect width="200" height="50" fill="tomato"/>
  <text y="25" x="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="24"
    textLength="160" dominant-baseline="middle">9AM to 5PM</text>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <rect width="200" height="50" fill="tomato"/>
  <text y="25" x="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="24"
    textLength="160" dominant-baseline="middle">12.00 to 17.00</text>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <rect width="200" height="50" fill="tomato"/>
  <text y="25" x="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" font-size="24"
    textLength="160" dominant-baseline="middle">9AM to 5PM</text>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <rect width="200" height="50" fill="tomato"/>
  <text y="25" x="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="system-ui" font-size="24"
    textLength="160" dominant-baseline="middle">9AM to 5PM</text>
</svg>
```