# Issues Displaying SVG Images within HTML

Tags: html, svg

I have a question regarding the display of SVG files in HTML. The SVG from the given URL displays correctly when viewed directly in a browser. However, when I reference this SVG in another website's HTML using the img tag or as a background-image, the image specified within the SVG using the xlink:href attribute doesn't appear. Could you please explain the reason for this issue and provide a solution? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

SVG URL:
`https://openseauserdata.com/files/f901a9d6d0d16c8aeb984921ca37eab4.svg`

Website displaying this SVG using an img tag:
`https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/mumbai/0x0b2057d19e128e9acd147db906ba01fe44fb8c50/0`

While it was closed due to its similarity to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903224/how-many-levels-of-recursion-does-svg-support), I'd like to point out that it's distinct because the issue with webp not displaying also exists, which makes it different.

Comment: It must have been blocked by CORS policy. Try uploading the svg image to youn own site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If it is difficult to upload the svg image to my own site, how can i fix the cors problem?

Comment: webp is external to the SVG/image so the duplicate is valid.