# How to give an svg a background-image?

Tags: html, svg

I have 2 `.svg`'s:

1. `map.svg` - https://github.com/djaiss/mapsicon/blob/master/all/ad/vector.svg
2. `flag.svg`- https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags/blob/master/svg/ad.svg

I want to **inject the flag.svg** as a background-image **into the map.svg**

What's the way to do it?
Is there's an attribute for the svg or a sub element which is right for this kind of task?

Here's my snippet:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width= '400' height='400' version="1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <path d="M372 98.3c-5.8 3.5-14.9 8.7-20.3 11.6l-9.8 5.3-5.7-1.9c-5.5-1.9-6-1.9-13.4-.3-4.2 1-8.3 2-9.2 2.3-.8.3-3.6 4.4-6.2 9.1-2.6 4.7-5.3 8.6-5.8 8.6-.6 0-8.4.9-17.4 1.9l-16.3 1.9-9.5-2.9c-5.2-1.5-9.8-3-10.2-3.3-.4-.2-4.7-5.4-9.7-11.5-7-8.5-9.6-11-11.5-11-1.4-.1-10.4 1.1-20.1 2.6l-17.6 2.6-2.8 9.5c-2.3 8.1-2.6 10.6-2.1 17.1l.7 7.6-11.5 12-11.5 12-.1 10.2v10.1l3.8.9 3.7.9.6 7.9c.5 7 1.2 9.4 5.8 18.9 3.9 8 5.8 13.4 7.2 20.8 1 5.4 1.9 10.6 1.9 11.6s-3.3 3.9-8.5 7.2l-8.5 5.5v12l-9.8 2.8c-6.8 2-12.6 4.7-19.4 8.8l-9.8 5.8-6.7-2.8c-4.9-2.1-9.7-3.2-17.2-4-5.8-.5-10.8-.8-11.1-.6-.4.2-1 3.9-1.4 8.2-.3 4.3-1.1 12.8-1.7 19-1.3 12.6-.2 11.4-11.6 12.8l-5.2.7-6.7 10.4-6.6 10.5-5.2-.3-5.1-.3-.8 7.6-.9 7.5 6 12c4.1 8.2 8.1 14.3 12.7 19.6l6.6 7.6 7.2.7c13 1.1 12.3.7 15.2 9.6 1.5 4.3 2.5 8.3 2.3 8.9-.2.5-6.3 6-13.6 12.3-12.3 10.5-14.4 11.9-27 17.6-7.5 3.5-14.2 6.8-14.9 7.4-.6.7-6.1 13.4-12.2 28.3s-13.3 32-16.1 37.9c-2.8 6-4.9 11.4-4.7 11.9.3.6 1.6 1.8 3 2.5 2.5 1.3 3 1.1 12.1-6.3l9.5-7.6h7.7c7.1 0 9.4-.6 25.8-6.7 10-3.6 18.6-6.6 19.1-6.6.8 0 26.1 16.3 29.3 18.8.1.1-.2 3.2-.8 6.8-1 6.3-.9 6.8 3.4 18.8 2.4 6.8 4.7 13.2 5.1 14.1.5 1.2 2.3 2 5.5 2.4 2.6.3 5.3.9 5.9 1.3 1 .6 24.9 50.9 25.4 53.4.1.5-5 5-11.3 9.9-6.3 4.9-16.3 13.2-22.2 18.4-10.4 9.2-10.8 9.7-11.4 14.5-.4 2.7-1.2 5.5-1.8 6.3-.6.8-8 4.6-16.4 8.5L82.9 693l-19.7.1c-10.8 0-24.2.6-29.7 1.2l-10 1.2-5.7 8.5c-5.3 7.8-6.3 8.7-11.2 10.5-3 1.1-5.7 2.3-6 2.6-.5.5.3 3.4 2.9 10.7.3.9 2.1.6 7.1-1.3 3.6-1.4 7.2-2.5 8-2.5.7 0 2.1 2.5 3.1 5.6l1.7 5.6 8.6-.6c4.7-.3 13-.8 18.5-1.1l10-.6L75 747.4 89.5 762l-3.8 7.3-3.8 7.2 2.9 13.4 3 13.4 4.9 4.2c2.6 2.3 6.1 5.3 7.8 6.7l2.9 2.6-7.8 8.7-7.9 8.6 3.2 10.7c1.8 5.8 5.7 15.4 8.7 21.3l5.4 10.8-6.7-2.5c-3.7-1.4-7.2-2.8-7.7-3.2-2-1.2 3.6 5.6 12.1 14.6l8.8 9.3L131 898c18.4 2.8 20.9 3.5 45.6 12l26.2 9h43.3l22.5 6.6 22.6 6.6 16.1-5.8 16.2-5.7 28.5-1.8c15.7-1 30.8-1.8 33.6-1.8l5.1-.1.7-4.8c.3-2.6.9-10.6 1.3-17.9l.6-13.2 8.6-2.9c4.7-1.6 8.6-3.3 8.6-3.8s-.4-8.2-.9-17.1c-.8-16-.8-16.3 1.9-24.3 2.1-6.2 3.1-8.1 4.8-8.5 3-.7 16.8-3.5 17.1-3.5.2 0 4.3 5.2 9 11.5 7.7 10.3 9.3 11.8 14.2 14 8.7 3.8 8.2 4.1 12.8-6.8 3.2-7.6 6.3-12.6 13.6-22.1l9.4-12.3 13.6-7.7 13.5-7.8 9.1 4.7 9 4.8 17-1.7c20.8-2 23-2 37.6.1l11.8 1.6 5.7-5c3.2-2.7 6.3-5.2 7-5.6.6-.4 3.7.5 6.8 2l5.6 2.8 9.1-4.9 9-4.8 4.9 4.8 4.9 4.8 8.6-2.8 8.6-2.8 3.1-6.9c2.5-5.9 3.7-7.4 7.8-9.9 5.5-3.3 5.5-2.3.1-14l-2.9-6.6 1.9-4.8c1-2.6 3.4-12.1 5.3-21 4.9-23.5 5.8-27 6.6-28 .4-.4 17.2-2.6 37.4-4.7l36.6-3.9 15.4 11.6 15.5 11.6 3.7-3.3c2.1-1.8 11-10.1 19.8-18.5 8.8-8.3 20.8-19.1 26.7-23.9 8.6-7 11-9.4 11.8-12.4.5-2 1-11.2 1-20.5v-16.9l-4.5-5.5c-2.5-3-4.5-5.7-4.5-6.1 0-.4 2.5-1.5 5.5-2.5l5.5-1.7 6.9-13.7c6.5-13 6.9-14.4 8.6-26.1 1.8-11.9 1.8-12.6 0-19.6l-1.8-7.3 3.8-9.4 3.8-9.3-1.8-13.1-1.8-13.1 6.8-12.5c6.2-11.7 7.4-13.3 16.9-22 17.8-16.6 16.3-15.7 30.9-19.9l13.2-3.8 11.7 1 11.8 1.1 10.7-5.8c13.1-7 38.6-26.7 37.9-29.3-1.4-4.9-8.9-28.7-9.2-29.2-.2-.3-10.8 1.2-23.5 3.3l-23.2 3.9-17.1-5.7c-12.3-4.1-21.4-7.9-32.6-13.7-14.1-7.4-16.4-8.2-26-9.9-5.8-1-13.5-1.8-17.2-1.8-5.8 0-7.5-.4-11.8-3.1-4-2.5-4.9-3.5-4.5-5.2.3-1.2 1.6-9.1 3-17.5l2.5-15.3 6-8c4-5.3 6-9 6-10.9 0-2.1 1.1-3.6 4.7-6.4 2.6-2 7.3-6.7 10.5-10.5l5.9-7-3-5.8c-1.6-3.2-3.2-8.4-3.6-11.6-.4-3.1-1.1-5.7-1.5-5.7-.4 0-2.9 1.9-5.6 4.2-2.7 2.3-5.6 4.8-6.5 5.5-1.4 1.2-3.9 1.1-16.5-.6-8.1-1.2-18.3-2.1-22.5-2.1-6.4 0-9.6-.6-18.1-3.7-9.4-3.4-11.1-4.4-19.6-11.8-12.2-10.8-17.5-13-38-15.6l-15.4-2-10.2 6.1-10.2 6-10.5.1c-5.7 0-12.6.4-15.3.8-6.2 1-13.4-.5-19.8-4.3-4.4-2.6-4.7-3-5.4-8.2-.4-3.5-1.2-5.8-2.3-6.3-2.3-1.3-37.5-9.1-47.5-10.5l-8.1-1.2-9.9 4.9-9.9 4.9-7.7-1.1c-5.2-.7-8.9-.7-11.1 0-4.6 1.3-15.9.2-24.7-2.6-8.5-2.7-12.1-2.2-18.6 2.6-3.3 2.4-5 2.9-9.8 2.9H520l-6.6-13.3c-3.7-7.2-7.1-13.5-7.7-13.8-.5-.4-2.8-1-5.1-1.3-4.1-.7-34.6-7.3-37.8-8.2-1.6-.5-1.8-1.9-1.8-10.3v-9.8l-4.5-1.7c-2.4-1-4.6-2.5-4.9-3.4-.2-.9-.8-5.8-1.1-10.9l-.7-9.2-7.1-.3-7.1-.3-6.3-8.9c-3.4-4.8-6.4-9.1-6.7-9.3-.3-.3-4 .7-8.4 2.2l-7.8 2.8-11.5-8.6c-6.4-4.8-11.8-8.7-12-8.7-.2 0-5.1 2.8-10.9 6.3z"/>
 
 <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Flag_of_Norway%2C_state.svg" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg) could help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed SVG in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Comment: @RobertLongson 
The post you mentioned was giving a background to a path, and it was to complicated to understand how to I manage to mingle with my complex path and fill it with my second svg as a background

Comment: You'll have to give us more than that. How are we supposed to know why you find it "complicated to understand"? You've not shown us either file's contents, nor how you tried to apply the answer in the question I linked and what the problem was with that attempt.

Comment: @rojadesign
you're right, thanks for the feedback. I updated the post with my 2 svg's, and a snippet my failing code

Answer (score 0):

Use the image element and reference your SVG file.

```
<svg>
  <image href="flag.svg"/>
</svg>
```

then set the `map.svg` as the background image.

Comment: What do you mean to reference your SVG file?
How do I reference it ? can you please be more specific?

Comment: `<image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="flag.svg" />`
 this line will include your flag.svg inside your map.svg

Comment: Note: `xlink:href` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href).