# embedded svg rendering issues with chrome

Tags: html, svg

When I embed an SVG inside an SVG in chrome, some issues occur. One of these issues is that I can't apply "filter: drop-shadow" on the child SVG, although this works fine on Firefox. It works on chrome when I apply it on the parent SVG.

Is it a bad habit to embed an SVG in an SVG, or there is something wrong with my code?

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgb(155, 246, 255, 0.7),
    rgba(189, 178, 255, 0.9)
  );
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.test1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: drop-shadow(-3px 1px 24px rgba(40, 245, 4, 1));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-3px 1px 24px rgba(40, 245, 4, 1));
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(-3px 1px 24px rgba(40, 245, 4, 1));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <svg height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <g>
          <svg
            class="test1"
            height="200"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            version="1.1"
          >
            <rect class="7-1" x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
          </svg>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this code if I apply the class "test1" to the parent SVG, It will work fineو, otherwise, it is not working at all on chrome but it's working on Firefox

Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed SVG in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg)

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the result
https://imgur.com/dYYhN9A

Comment: @ChrisW. 
I tried the solutions in this post, I included the nested SVG via Image element and the problem still exists. It works on Firefox but doesn't work on chrome. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that CSS filters are not working on nested SVG elements, they are currently work cross-browser **only** on outermost`<svg>` elements and fail for **any** child element. Only Firefox implements that part of the [filter spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1).

You can find that information on the [Mozilla developer network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) in the [Browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility). For some reason, the information is missing on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-filters). It is always a good idea to check whether browsers implement features before using them, but also a sad truth that there is no rigorous documentation of SVG features across browsers.

How to apply a drop shadow to SVG content is described in [SVG drop shadow using css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3). But again, check carefully for support of features.

The use of nested `<svg>` is not a "bad habit", but you should only expect the usage defined in the [1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement) to have good support.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything is clear now, I really appreciate your help <3