# Embed inline SVG in inline SVG?

Tags: svg

I've come across:

[Embed SVG in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg)

But I want to embed an inline SVG into an inline SVG on the same page. This is for a CodePen file, but I've replicated it here.

I want to be able to see 2 LinkedIn icons, but right now I'm not seeing the 2nd one.

```css
body {  transition: all .3s ease; }

/* Set icon size */
.svg-icon svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.svg-icon svg > g rect {
  fill: gray;
}
.svg-icon svg > g circle {
  fill: gray;
}

.svg-background {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.svg-background:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Dark Mode Settings */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  p { color: #fff; }
  .color-scheme--light, .color-scheme--no-preference {
    display:none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg {
    color: white;
  }
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #D83933;
  } 
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #D83933;
  } 
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
   p { color: #000; }
  .color-scheme--dark, 
  .color-scheme--no-preference {
    display:none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg {
    color: #1B1B1B;
  }
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #A23737;
  } 
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #A23737;
  } 
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference) { 
  body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
   p { color: #000; }
  .color-scheme--light, 
  .color-scheme--dark {
    display:none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg path {
    fill: #1B1B1B;
  } 
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #A23737;
  } 
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #A23737;
  } 
}

/* Hide visually */
.visually-hidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <span class="svg-icon">
    <span class="visually-hidden">LinkedIn</span>
    <svg id="linkedin-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 640 640" aria-hidden="true">
      <g class="svg-background">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" ry="150" rx="150" />
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.65, 0.65)">
        <path fill="currentColor" transform="translate(160, 160)" d="M228.582 205.715h126.462v64.832h1.83c17.611-31.595 60.675-64.832 124.892-64.832C615.303 205.715 640 288.818 640 396.926v220.219H508.116V421.93c0-46.536-.969-106.442-68.576-106.442-68.67 0-79.194 50.658-79.194 103.052v198.605H228.581v-411.43zM137.152 91.43c0 37.855-30.721 68.576-68.576 68.576-37.855 0-68.587-30.721-68.587-68.576 0-37.855 30.732-68.576 68.587-68.576 37.855 0 68.576 30.721 68.576 68.576zM-.011 205.715h137.163v411.43H-.011v-411.43z" />
      </g>
    </svg></span></a>

<br /><br /><br /><br />

  <span class="svg-icon">
    <use href="#linkedin-svg"/>
    </svg></span></a>
```

I should be able embed a inline SVG inline.

Comment: In the code you have 2 (two)  closing </a> elements you never open, a closing </svg> element you never open and an <use> element outside an <svg> element. Please efit your question and use avalid code

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the main take-away is that you need to be more consistent with your HTML markup.

With the `<use>` element you are creating a shadow DOM of the element with the ID that you are referring to. So, the original element will be copied into `<use>`. Therefore the parent of `<use>` makes the "context" of the original element. You almost had it right, but you can see in my code that `<svg id="linkedin-svg">` is an element inside a `<svg>` that is identical to the parent `<svg>` of the `<use>`. Well, a bit confusing explanation -- I hope it makes sense.

I also changed a bit in the CSS. Not the hover works better.

```css
body {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}


/* Set icon size */

.svg-icon svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

svg>g {
  fill: gray;
}

.svg-background {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

svg:hover .svg-background {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Dark Mode Settings */

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  p {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .color-scheme--light,
  .color-scheme--no-preference {
    display: none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg {
    color: white;
  }
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #D83933;
  }
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #D83933;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  p {
    color: #000;
  }
  .color-scheme--dark,
  .color-scheme--no-preference {
    display: none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg {
    color: #1B1B1B;
  }
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #A23737;
  }
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #A23737;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference) {
  body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  p {
    color: #000;
  }
  .color-scheme--light,
  .color-scheme--dark {
    display: none;
  }
  /* SVG Icons */
  .svg-icon svg path {
    fill: #1B1B1B;
  }
  /* Hover color */
  .svg-icon svg:hover g path {
    color: #A23737;
  }
  .svg-icon svg:hover {
    fill: #A23737;
  }
}


/* Hide visually */

.visually-hidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="svg-icon">
  <span class="visually-hidden">LinkedIn</span>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 640">
    <svg id="linkedin-svg">
      <g class="svg-background">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" ry="150" rx="150" />
      </g>
      <g transform="scale(0.65, 0.65)">
        <path fill="currentColor" transform="translate(160, 160)" d="M228.582 205.715h126.462v64.832h1.83c17.611-31.595 60.675-64.832 124.892-64.832C615.303 205.715 640 288.818 640 396.926v220.219H508.116V421.93c0-46.536-.969-106.442-68.576-106.442-68.67 0-79.194 50.658-79.194 103.052v198.605H228.581v-411.43zM137.152 91.43c0 37.855-30.721 68.576-68.576 68.576-37.855 0-68.587-30.721-68.587-68.576 0-37.855 30.732-68.576 68.587-68.576 37.855 0 68.576 30.721 68.576 68.576zM-.011 205.715h137.163v411.43H-.011v-411.43z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</span>
<span class="svg-icon">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 640">
    <use href="#linkedin-svg"/>
  </svg>
</span>
```